# How to make comparison inside a render in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering a component inside another component and it looks like this:

```
render() {
    return (

        <MyComponent
            value={this.state.measurement.Value}
            unit="kg"
        />
    );
}
```

What I want to do is to change the unit of measurement if the value accomplishes a condition. For example, if `value > 1000`, unit should be `tons` instead of `kg`.

I know that it cannot be added an if statement there, I tried to do it like this but it doesn't work.

```
render() {
    return (

        <MyComponent
            value={this.state.measurement.Value}
            unit="kg"
            (value > 1000){
                 unit="tons"
            }
        />
    );
}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
render() {
    return (

        <MyComponent
            value={this.state.measurement.Value}
            unit={this.state.measurement.Value > 1000 ? "tons" : "kg"}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ternary expression.

```
unit={ this.state.measurement.Value>1000 ? 'tons' : 'kg' }
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like this approach.

```
render() {
  const value = this.state.measurement.Value
  return (
    <MyComponent
      value={value}
      unit={value > 1000 ? "tons" : "kg"}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ternary condition expression:

```
render() {
    const Value = this.state.measurement.Value;
    const unit = Value  > 1000 ? "tons" : "kg" 
    return (

        <MyComponent
            value={Value}
            unit={unit}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a `unit` variable outside the return:

```
render() {
  const value = this.state.measurement.Value;
  const unit = value > 1000 ? 'tons' : 'kg';

  return (
    <MyComponent
      value={value}
      unit={unit}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
render() {
    let measureVal = (this.state.measurement.Value < 1000) ? 'kg' : 'tons';
    return (

        <MyComponent
            value={this.state.measurement.Value}
            unit={measureVal}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
render() {
 return (
    <MyComponent
        value={this.state.measurement.Value}
        unit= {this.state.measurement.Value > 1000 ? "tons" : "kg" }
    />
 );
}
```